# Dropdown within Kendo Grid in Form > Add New Record Creates Uninitialized Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a Kendo grid with dropdown templates in cells users can submit as part of a form, using these two articles:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-dropdownlist-column-template
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-submit-with-form

The dropdowns look good when they bind to the data, but when adding a new record or modifying an existing one, they quickly break and become text inputs.

Here's my code. https://dojo.telerik.com/@ben-clark/uREGoBUD

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you tried, we cant help you without it!

Comment: Hi @KevinHernandez! Thanks for offering. Can you click my dojo link there? That will get you the hybrid of the code from those articles.

Comment: I can see in the console your result is null so the field is defaulting as a result, possibly. Check that section in your code where you are if elsing to null.

Comment: Very good, @NathanielFlick! I am not sure how to bind the dropdown cell, but I hadn't seen the console. Good catch.

Comment: It looks like you just have to leave edit mode after dropdown change event.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosMartins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems with my initial attempt.

1. I needed to add RowID values to the existing selected values.
2. I needed to prevent going into the 'edit' mode automatically on new rows.

```
    // in the grid object
    beforeEdit: function(e){
        if (!e.model.isNew()) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

Huge credit to @CarlosMartins for the abstract comment.

Solution code: https://dojo.telerik.com/@ben-clark/uREGoBUD/10

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line `editable: "incell",` from your `grid` object and it will work!